# Connect to database on another computer not on the same network with Windows Form C++

Tags: c++, mysql, winforms

I'm working on a Windows Form C++ app that send my girlfriend's data of this app to my computer. We are far away and not on the same network.

Is there any way to do that? Can MySQL do that?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use vpn.

Comment: I will research that. Thanks

Comment: MySQL is too heavy for that, consider using sqlite3 or msaccess

Comment: @seccpur: That comment makes no sense at all. How do you know how powerful the computers are? Besides, MySQL will work on a small Raspberry Pi. "Too heavy"?!

Comment: @MSalters: Heavy, not in the dB engine context, but installation of the server, c++ connect, export of dB, client side installation req will be overwhelming, as the OP just want to send limited data from a front-end.